# ReadError while installing using pip and tar.gz

Tags: python, pip, gzip, tar

I have been trying to install something using

```
pip3 install http://gitlab.com/company/projects/package/-/archive/latest/package-latest.tar.gz
```

and it's giving me following error.

```
OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'<!')
```

Some tracebacks and then.

```
tarfile.ReadError: not a gzip file
```

But when I am downloading `package-latest.tar.gz` and then install it with `pip install package-latest.tar.gz` it is working fine.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have exactly the same issue. I try to install "pip install http://xxx" and I got a error message that it is not a gzip file. When I download the file and pip install from local file it works fine. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @FCastell, please see if this helps: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#prefill-personal-access-token-name-and-scopes

Comment: Thanks @shivankgtm. In my case there is no authentication problem. What happened is that python was not downloading the file due to permissions settings on the server side. Permission was granted and pip install from http worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that some authentication / authorization (password) is required to access this URL? That could explain that an HTML page is sent back as an error message (those commonly start with `<!`) since *pip* is not authorized.

If it is indeed the case, you would need to figure out how to pass the credentials to the server via *pip*. Maybe something like the following can help (but there are probably other, better solutions):

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#basic-authentication-credentials

It could also be any other (temporary) issue in the client/server communication, so that the server might not be able to serve the file and just sends back some error message as HTML.

Comment: That helped me to look for https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#personal-access-tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the message implies that the file was downloaded but has some integrity problem that generates the "Not a gzipped file". In my case i found out that python was not downloading the file due to permissions on the server side. Once permissions were granted it worked. In my case would be nice if the message simply indicate that the file was not downloaded.

Please note that I was downloading from my own domain. Using chmod 644 for files and chmod 755 for folders solved the issue.